# How to get initialised, non sequential array indexes in C

Tags: c, arrays, clang

I'm coming from high level languages and trying to learn C and improve my knowledge of how stuff works in lower levels.

So i'm trying to understand how is it possible to get only initialised array indexes.
They could be non sequential so simply iterating over the array won't do the job.

So suppose we've got an array of integers of size 20,
Only a few elements in this array has been initialised with value '1'

How can I know which indexes has been initialised?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int data[20];

    data[1] = 1;
    data[5] = 1;
    data[8] = 1;
    data[16] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

so in example above how to get 1,5,8,16 as result?
Is that even the right way of working with arrays in C?

Comment: see also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/designated-initializers-c/

Comment: uninitialized variables may also get garbage values. It depends on your dataset i.e If you have any specific range of values for array, you can have that check to find uninitialized values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't remember which ones got initialized and which ones didn't. In your example, you could for instance initialize them all to `0` and then check all the values that aren't `0`.

```
int main() {
    int data[20] = {0};

    data[1] = 1;
    data[5] = 1;
    data[8] = 1;
    data[16] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (data[i]) {
            printf("data[%d] is initialized to %d\n", i, data[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
data[1] is initialized to 1
data[5] is initialized to 1
data[8] is initialized to 1
data[16] is initialized to 1
```

---

Explanation: `int data[20] = {0};` tells it to explicitly initialize the first element to `0`, and the rest is default-initialized (which is `0` for `int`). So `int data[20] = {5};` would set the first element to `5`, but the rest is still set to `0`.

Comment: Be aware, however, that the global data are initialized all to zeros by default. So it depends on the declaration location: if the array is automatic (local, on the stack), it may contain any garbage, until explicitly filled; if the array is static, global, it is initialized with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

The rest elements of array will contain totally random values, possibly 1, so you may find more than 4 elements that contain 1 as value.

In order to initialize an array you have to iterate it or use `memset(data, 0, sizeof(data))`.

The way you set `1` in some elements is more assigning and not initializing.

Comment: The rest of the array cannot be presumed to hold any values at all, random or otherwise. Per the C standard, the values of the uninitialized elements are unspecified. As used in the C standard, this does not just mean that an element holds some value not determined by the program, such as whatever happened to be remaining in memory from previous operations, but that its value is unspecified each time it is used. It could appear to be different at different times, even with no intervening changes by the program. The C standard affords implementations this latitude to permit optimization.

Comment: One does not “have to” iterate or use `memset` to initialize an array. Except for variable-length arrays, an array may be initialized in its definition as in `int data[20] = { … };`. Any values not explicitly listed in the initializers will be initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

In C, array contains values themselves, rather than references to values.  For your `int data [20]` there will be 20 slots allocated in the stack, with each slots holding single value of type `int`.  Allocated slots are not cleared, so initial values of array elements will be the data stored in these stack slots by whoever used them before.  Assignments you made for array elements, such as `data[8] = 1;` do not initialize array elements, they just replace current values of the elements with a new values.

In other words, all the elements of your array are initialized right after array declaration.  In your particular case they are initialized with some garbage values from the stack.  If you want to initialize them with some particular values, you should use array initializer like this:

```
int data[20] = {
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
};
```

This apply to non-array variables as well.  In contract with some other languages, such as Java, you cannon initialize variable after declaration, but only within declarations.  So:

```
int a = 13; // Initialize to 13
int b; // Initialize to garbage from stack

a = 11; // Just assignment, not initialization
b = 17; // Yet another assignment, not initialization
```

Comment: One cannot rely on array elements containing whatever data was stored on the stack previously. Per the C standard, the values of the uninitialized elements are unspecified. As used in the C standard, this does not just mean that an element holds some value not determined by the program, such as whatever happened to be remaining in memory from previous operations, but that its value is unspecified each time it is used. It could appear to be different at different times, even with no intervening changes by the program. The C standard affords implementations this latitude to permit optimization.